# Show posts of parent in edit.php

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, wp-admin, editor

I'm creating a post type for a site where there 4 main 'parent' pages in a custom post type. For the sake of argument the post type is 'schools'

the 4 (of many) parents are:

Cambridge
Teesside
Newcastle
Sunderland

The post type 'schools' is a hierarchical post type, and what I would like to do is treat any children of the top 4 pages as a blogroll in the individual pages. To do this I would like to add a custom menu item on the post type menu that looks something like this

edit.php?post_type=schools&parent=123

Is this possible? If not, does anyone know of another way I can achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: No, I am still looking around. I think I will have to add a hook to the post_save hook (or the hook that is called when a post is saved) that does it manually depending on a variable passed. I couldnt find any query like above that provided what I needed. I'll be sure to update here if I find a solution. It's very useful if you are using Wordpress as a CMS and are using hierarchical pages/posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just using 4 posts, I think that `schools` would better be suited as taxonomy terms rather than a post type. Associate your Posts with the school tax term. I would then create custom templates for each of those terms.

- taxonomy-schools-cambridge.php
- taxonomy-schools-teeside.php
- taxonomy-schools-newcastle.php
- taxonomy-schools-sunderland.php

Within those templates, use a WP_Query object to surface those posts. Read more about WP_Query taxonomy parameters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Your URLs would still be /schools/sunderland/ etc...

This seems like an easier out-of-the-box approach rather than creating new functions to do the same thing. Though, this comes down to UI preference at the end of the day.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. There is a few issues with this answer (Although I appreciate the time, and I also appreciate my op wasnt too specific!). There could have any number of parents, hence creating a manual taxonomy template for each parent would be unwieldy. This would work perfectly if the number of parents was specific.